# How to debounceTime in OnPush Component (stackblitz)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, debouncing

I am learning RXJS and have the following context:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, tap, debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeProvider {

  private counter: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  public counter$ = this.counter.asObservable() // .pipe(debounceTime(2000))

  constructor(
  ) {
    interval(1000).subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      this.counter.next(value);
    })
  };

}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeProvider } from './some.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>{{ provider.counter$ | async }}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  constructor(public provider: SomeProvider) {

  }
}
```

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdvwnj

So question - right now the component updates counter in the component's template every second.
I would like to simply debounce it using debounceTime. I thought it will be as easy as adding a pipe to Observable with debounceTime operator. But if I uncomment that change - counter is not even there.

Question:

- how to apply debounceTime in this scenario correctly
- why if we add pipe with debounceTime async pipe inside the template stops working (and requires additional change detection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting what is already written in *docs*, lets try to understand in simple *layman language*.

**debounceTime()** - It is a RxJs operator which listen for all the incoming data-stream for **a given time-limit** and only forwards the **last one**.

Example :-

```
MyAwesomeObservable().pipe(debounceTime(10000))
```

This means that debouncetime will not forward data-stream until 10secs elapsed. During that 10secs, if some new data-stream comes, debounceTime will again starts waiting for 10secs.

Your-Case :-

Since  `interval(1000)` passes data every 1sec, `debounceTime(2000)` wait of 2sec never ends.

**interval > debouncetime** ,than your code will work.

Comment: And in regard to Change-Detection, its a separate time, mostly to optimize DOM updation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime)

> Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed **without another source emission**.

This will work if the time passed to the `debounceTime` < time passed to `interval`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ogxkbd)

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers mentioned, because your `debounceTime` is higher than the `interval()`, it will cause all interval emissions to be 'debounced'.

If you want to debounce an interval to only emit every 2 seconds, instead of 1 second, and you don't have control over the interval time, you can use a filter:

```
public counter$ = this.counter.asObservable().pipe(
  filter((idx) => !(idx % 2))
)
```

This will make your counter emit only at even emissions.

[see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4kfyn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsome.service.ts)